# need space between two words in python with two inputs

Tags: python

I am trying to put in 2 inputs then get them as an output, but I cant seem to get a space between them at the end . I have tried a + sign, space between x and y, and a comma and none work.

[image]

Comment: Post text, not images of text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

A formatted string will work nicely here.

We can provide variables to a string that has special format markers, like so:

```
print('{0} {1}'.format(word1, word2))
```

Or, more easily, a string concatenation:

```
print(word1 + ' ' + word2)
```

Comment: Also `print(f'{word1} {word2}')`

Comment: @cricket_007 I learn something new every day

Comment: It's a relatively new Python3 feature